# Read_excel reads cells with formulae as NaN (instead of the actual value)

Tags: python-3.x

```
path = "C:\\Users\\Adam\\Desktop\\Stock Trackers\\New folder\\New folder\\Stock Tracker WK36 mTeam.xlsx"

df = pd.read_excel(path,usecols="A:D,R",index_col=None)
```

Column R (in the file path above) is a column with a simple SUM formula. When I use `read_excel` as above, Columns A-D (in the resulting dataframe df) are fine as these are constants but column R is displayed with all NaN. How can I use pandas to read the underlying cell value instead of displaying NaN?

Comment: You can't. Excel doesn't store the cell value in the file, it calculates when you open the file.

Comment: I see. Is there a way I can convert the file to a "flat file" (i.e. one without formulae but just values) first so it can be read by pd.read_excel? I have built a script around pd.read_excel hence my question.

Comment: There's a way to trigger on File/Save to run some code to do the transformation.

Comment: So I am basically trying to write a script to concatenate particular columns from multiple different files (all same structure) and create an overall master file. The issue is that these files are invoices and new invoices are generated each week. How would I implement the above practically given the context?

Comment: So you don't have any control over the files you're using? That puts you in a really tough spot. I have no advice for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in getting the results of an excel formula computation into a data frame, Given an Excel sheet which looks like the following:
[image: Dummy Excel Sheet]
where the Total Qty column is a formula of the form sum(D:F), and the last column is a formula of the form G*C and the formula in cell h5 is sum(h2:h4).

When reading directly into a df using pandas.read_excel(fileName_) yields:

```
    item    Description Unit Cost   Part A Qty  Part B Qty  Part C Qty  Total Qty   Total Cost
0   1.0     System A    25.10        1.0        2.0            1.0            4.0      100.4
1   2.0      Part B     15.25        3.0        0.0            3.0            6.0      91.5
2   3.0      Part C     6.30         6.0        5.0            1.0            12.0     75.6
3    NaN    Sum        NaN           NaN        NaN            NaN            NaN      267.5
```

Comment: Did you see the part of the question that specifies the input is a .xlsx and not a.csv?

Comment: Yes, I did see excel, made a mistake in the command used, see update correcting the df creation command.

Comment: I'm impressed, it actually figured it out.  I tested it myself to be sure.

Comment: Yes, I know I was equally surprised.  Thought it would be more complicated.  Sometimes Christmas comes early

Comment: Sorry, not my question. Just a semi interested bystander, as the guy who said it couldn't be done.

Comment: Why do you keep making that comment?  OP is never going to see it; you need to comment on the question.